# Insert image in mysql using hibernate in jsp Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, servlets

i don't  know how to insert image into database using hibernate in jsp servlet.
im beginner of #java Developer

Thanks in advance

Comment: remove the `i don't know` and the last sentences from your question, the rest you can google, they are even giving vedios

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Solution](https://dzone.com/articles/how-load-or-save-image-using) it seemed to have worked perfectly for me.